# listview button not sending correct number to other activity

Tags: android-listview, xamarin.android

Buttons 1-7 (one for each row) correctly send numbers 1-7 to the edit component activity/screen (the numbers correspond to the row the button is on, based on the 'position'). However, when I tap on button 8-10, it for some reason sends numbers 1-3 to the edit component activity/screen and when I retry buttons 1-3 again, the numbers sent to the edit component activity are all out of sync.

I don't understand how the buttons for rows 1-7 send the correct numbers but all of a sudden row 8 and above don't.

The custom listview adapter class

```
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        //Row
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_row, null, false);
        }

        //Set component details
        TextView Category = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtViewCategory);
        Category.Text = allComponents[position].CategoryName;

        TextView Name = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtViewName);
        Name.Text = allComponents[position].Name;

        TextView Price = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtViewPrice);
        Price.Text = allComponents[position].Price;

        ImageButton editComponent = row.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imgBtnEditComponent);

        //Take the user to the edit screen for a given component
        if (!editComponent.HasOnClickListeners)
        {
            editComponent.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Declare the activityas intent
                var intent = new Intent(mContext, typeof(Edit_componentActivity));

                //Store the row position
                var rowPostion = (position + 1);

                //Transfer the component's row to the edit screen
                intent.PutExtra("edit_component_row_position", rowPostion);

                //Start the activity of intent
                mContext.StartActivity(intent);
            };
        }

        return row;
    }
```

The edit component activity

```
        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.edit_component);

        //Get the component's row position
        var editComponentRowPosition = Intent.GetIntExtra("edit_component_row_position", 0);

        Toast.MakeText(this, editComponentRowPosition.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();

        //Get the notes text view of the screen
        TextView editName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtEditEditComponentName);

        //Assign the notes text view the component's notes
        editName.Text = editComponentRowPosition.ToString();
```

Here are some screenshots.
[image]

Comment: Hi , could you share your sample link here , I will check it . By the way , I test in local site , can not reporoducing the problem .

Comment: What do you mean by sample link?

Comment: That means a sample project , only with the issue . If have time , you can share it here .

Comment: Hi, I have reproduced your problem , you can have a look at answer when you have time .

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your problem in my local site . The reason is that using the follow code to add click for Button , it will not be controled .When you click , `GetView` method will continue to invoke this method .It's not recommanded to use in Adapter .

```
editComponent.Click += (sender, e)
```

The **solution** that is using `SetOnClickListener` to replace it . As follow :

```
ImageButton editComponent = row.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.imgBtnEditComponent);
ImageButton.Tag = position; //Set position as Tag for button
ImageButton.SetOnClickListener(this);

public void OnClick(View v)
{
    int position = (int)v.Tag;
    Console.WriteLine("-------------button click---------------" + (position + 1));
    // Declare the activityas intent
    var intent = new Intent(mContext, typeof(Edit_componentActivity));

    //Store the row position
    var rowPostion = (position + 1);

    //Transfer the component's row to the edit screen
    intent.PutExtra("edit_component_row_position", rowPostion);

    //Start the activity of intent
    mContext.StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Not forget to Inherit `View.IOnClickListener` for adapter class .